# How to use Bcrypt in Postman pre-request script?

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

CryptoJS doesn't support Bcrypt, what can I do to use Bcrypt in Postman pre-request script?

Comment: An alternate way is to create separate api uses Bcrypt and call it from pre-request script.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I was thinking on doing that with a local service, but figured out that there should be another way because I plan on share this with a team, so it will be troublesome for them to setup servers just for bcypt usage